# Hamiltonian Groups of order $p^4$

Tags: group-theory

Does there exist a Hamiltonian group of order $p^4$, for $p \geq 3$?

Comment: Did you see the Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group? Read first three lines.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no Hamiltonian group of order $p^n$ for any $p\ge 3$ and any $n\ge 1$, since every Hamiltonian group is isomorphic to $Q_8\times P$
for some periodic abelian group $P$ which has no element of order $4$. Such a group has order divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 1):

No. A Dedekind group group is a group with all subgroups normal; a Hamiltonian group is a non-abelian Dedekind group.

> **Theorem (Dedekind, Baer)** All the subgroups of a group $G$ are normal if and only if $G$ is abelian or the direct product of a quaternion group of order $8$, an elementary abelian $2$-group and an abelian group with all its elements of odd order.

*Proof:* Over a page long, so I'm not copying it out! See pp.143-145, Derek J.S.Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups.

So for a Dedekind group $G$ to be non-abelian it requires the $Q_8$, therefore if we further require $G$ to have prime power order $p^n$ then $p=2$.